# JasperPrint sem ultilizar uma Collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports, pdf, inputstream

**Dúvida na utilização do JasperPrint sem uma Collection**

O código a seguir deveria gerar um PDF utilizando apenas um objeto da DTO ProntuarioRelatorioID, mas o problema é que a instância de JRBeanCollectionDataSource:

> JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, parametros, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados));

não aceita apenas um objeto e eu não consigo achar uma forma de utilizar sem uma Collection.

**Tenho o seguinte código:**

```
public byte[] relatorioPorPaciente(Long codigo) throws Exception {
    ProntuarioRelatorioID dados = this.agendamentoRepository.porPaciente(codigo);
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametros.put("ID", Long.valueOf(codigo));
    parametros.put("REPORT_LOCALE", new Locale("pt", "BR"));

    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/relatorios/relatorio_prontuario.jasper");

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, parametros,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados));

    return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
}
```